# flutter io.flutter.facade not found

Tags: flutter

i integrated my flutter view into existing android app’s fragment by calling

> Flutter.createView

but when building it throws error

> package io.flutter.facade not exists

anyone know how to fix it? thanks

Comment: Same, I'm also stuck. Did you find any solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

Because "io.flutter.facade.*" is discarded from Flutter version 1.12

see here:

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/34458

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Upgrading-pre-1.12-Android-projects

Answer (score 0):

Hi @Rocky I've somehow managed to start the flutter activity from the regular activity.

**MainActivity.kt (This is your host application class)**

```
 const val FLUTTER_ENGINE = "flutter_engine"

 class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

lateinit var context: Context

private val flutterEngine: FlutterEngine by lazy {
    FlutterEngine(this.applicationContext)
}

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    init()
}

private fun init() {
    context = this

    flutterEngine.dartExecutor.executeDartEntrypoint(
        DartExecutor.DartEntrypoint.createDefault()
    )

    FlutterEngineCache.getInstance().put(FLUTTER_ENGINE, flutterEngine)


    btnSend.setOnClickListener {
        sendNumbersToFlutter()
    }

}

private fun sendNumbersToFlutter() {
    startActivity(
        FlutterActivity.withCachedEngine(FLUTTER_ENGINE).build(
            context
        )
    )
}
```

}

**CRITICAL PART**

Add this line to your host's manifest

```
<activity android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity" />
```